# how can I do this in one query

Tags: sql

Table name: words
fields : wId, lemma, relatedId
data:
0 apple 1
1 pie -1

expected result:
wId = 0
lemma = apple
relatedWord = pie

Comment: You need more of a description of what you are trying to do here.  This simple example is not enough to define what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa3eb/3)

Details are given Below :

```
create table words (wId integer, 
                    lemma varchar(100), 
                    relatedId Integer);
Insert Into words values(0,'apple',1),(1,'pie',-1);

select t1.WID,t1.lemma as Lemma,t2.lemma as relatedWord 
from words t1,words t2
where t1.RelatedID = t2.WID
```

Answer (score 1):

This query can do what you want. As far as i understand your table words contains a foreign key between relatedld and wld. So this query should fulfill your needs:

```
SELECT t1.wld as wld, 
       t1.lemma as lemma, 
       t2.wld as relatedWorld
FROM words t1 JOIN words t2 ON t1.relatedld = t2.wld;
```